# Permission Denied error when I try to open the image file stored on the ZFS disk accessed through sshfs from another machine

Tags: linux, permissions, zfs, libvirt, sshfs

I would like to boot the FreeBSD 13.2 image file using Libvirt + virt-manager. I have stored the image on the external hard drive,"formatted" with ZFS while I'm using Devuan 5 installed on my ARM (32 bit) Chromebook,where I have access to the ZFS disk using sshfs using this command :

```
sshfs -o Compression=no -o allow_root -o transform_symlinks -o  password_stdin root@192.168.1.2:/mnt/zroot2/zroot2 /mnt/zroot2/zroot2 <<<  'pass'
```

This is the error I get when I try to boot the image file using virt-manager :

```
error : qemuProcessReportLogError:1990 : internal error: process exited  while
connecting to monitor: 2023-11-28T20:53:46.882586Z qemu-system-arm: -blockdev
{"driver":"file","filename":"/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Chromebook/FreeBSD-guestOS
/freebsd-kvm/FreeBSD-13.2-RELEASE-armv7.img","node-name":"libvirt-1-storage","auto-
read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}: Could not open '/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Chromebook
/FreeBSD-guestOS/freebsd-kvm/FreeBSD-13.2-RELEASE-armv7.img' : Permission denied
```

According with this post :

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/virt-manager-doesnt-work-permission-denied/108142

I tried to do the following :

```
root@devuan-bunsen:/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Chromebook/FreeBSD-guestOS/freebsd-kvm

getfacl /mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Chromebook/FreeBSD-guestOS/freebsd-kvm/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names

# file: mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Chromebook/FreeBSD-guestOS/freebsd-kvm/ 
# owner: root 
# group: root user::rwx group::rwx other::rwx

root@devuan-bunsen:/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Chromebook/FreeBSD-guestOS/freebsd-kvm

setfacl -m user:libvirt-qemu:--x /mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Chromebook/FreeBSD-guestOS/freebsd-kvm

setfacl: /mnt/zroot2/zroot2/OS/Chromebook/FreeBSD-guestOS/freebsd-kvm: Operation not supported
```

Can someone help me to understand where the error is and how to fix it ? thanks.